# How to fill the plot area using geom_raster or geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame:

```
 id  variable   value
 ID1    1A      91.98473282
 ID1    2A      72.51908397
 ID1    2B      62.21374046
 ID1    2D      69.08396947
 ID1    2F      83.39694656
 ID1    2G      41.60305344
 ID1    2H      63.74045802
 ID1    9A      58.40839695
 ID1    9C      61.10687023
 ID1    9D      50.76335878
 ID1    9K      58.46183206
```

I'm using ggplot2 to generate a heat map with the data:

```
     ggplot(data, aes(variable, id)) +
              geom_raster(aes(fill = value)) + 
              scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",
              high = "steelblue")
```

The plot looks like this:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26998371/plot.pdf

I would like for the tiles to fill the plot space on the y-axis rather than leave a space above and below.

I'm sure there is a simple answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) didn't work with the y-axis, but scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) will work on the x axis to fill the plot space.

Comment: It looks like `geom_raster(hpad=0, vpad=0)` is meant to do what you want, but I tested it and it has no effect on the plot. Maybe it isn't implemented yet?

Comment: Just for fun :-), try `scale_y_discrete(expand = c(-1, -1))` or some other values just to see if/how you can adjust the y scale. Make sure you're not running into some other limit on plot space vs. plot window margins and the like.

Comment: Tried scale_y_discrete(expand = c(-1, -1)). No luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**  It appears that the issue has been resolved in recent versions of ggplot2.

It's something to do with there being just one level in the `id` factor. Change the `id` factor to numeric, or change the `id` factor so it has two levels, then the tiles fill the space. Also, `coord_equal()` with the original `id` factor will give a long narrow plot, but again filling the space.

```
## Your data
df = read.table(text = "
id  variable   value
ID1    1A      91.98473282
ID1    2A      72.51908397
ID1    2B      62.21374046
ID1    2D      69.08396947
ID1    2F      83.39694656
ID1    2G      41.60305344
ID1    2H      63.74045802
ID1    9A      58.40839695
ID1    9C      61.10687023
ID1    9D      50.76335878
ID1    9K      58.46183206", header = TRUE, sep = "")

library(ggplot2)

 # Change the id factor
 df$id2 = 1                   # numeric
 df$id3 = c(rep("ID1", 5), rep("ID2", 6))      # more than one level

 # Using the numeric version
 ggplot(df, aes(variable, id2)) +
          geom_raster(aes(fill = value)) + 
          scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1, labels = "ID1", expand = c(0,0)) + 
          scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
          scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",
          high = "steelblue")
```

[image]

```
# Two levels in the ID factor
ggplot(df, aes(variable, id3)) +
          geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
          scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",
          high = "steelblue") 

# Using coord_equal() with the original id variable
ggplot(df, aes(variable, id)) +
          geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
          scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",
          high = "steelblue") +
          coord_equal()
```

Comment: Thanks Sandy. The numeric version works well for what I'm trying to do. Any idea why it won't work with the discrete variable?

Comment: @Mike, No ideas. But it could have been a bug, which has been fixed in the development version. I've just run your code using the development version and the tiles fill the space on the y-axis. The development version will shortly be released - [see here](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/860293253a9d0cc8). If you can't wait for version 0.9.1, [see here](https://github.com/wch/ggplot2/wiki/Installing-the-development-version-of-ggplot2) for instructions on installing the development version.

Comment: @Mike, I mean "the development version of `ggplot2`".

Comment: `ggplot2 0.9.1` is on cran now. Upgrade and all should be well.

Comment: how about in `plot`? if I want to do it with `plot`?